Setting up Reverse Proxy for Keycloak
I need assistance with configuring a reverse proxy in front of Keycloak. Specifically, I aim to access gitlab.com through this setup, but I find myself redirected to Keycloak instead.
Here’s what I have done so far: Created a configuration file in sites-available
cat 01-test.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name gitlab.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /users/sign_in {
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8443/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=security-admin-console&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8443%2Fadmin%2Fmaster%2Fconsole%2F&state=f4bba86c-49b7-4861-86c8-1035cdf6cd4e&response_mode=query&response_type=code&scope=openid&nonce=c4586d26-00bf-40a8-8c9e-ed8aa878ee7a&code_challenge=DMO-Wx4xR0ttBQLAN6ulWtBCO8EmhaCK7vsaPwaYS5U&code_challenge_method=S256;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
    proxy_cookie_path / "/; HTTPOnly; Secure; SameSite=None";
}

and tried to run keycloak x-forwarded
As this is my first attempt at configuring a reverse proxy, I would appreciate any guidance or documentation that could help me proceed further. Could you please advise on the additional steps I should take to ensure the proper functioning of the reverse proxy in redirecting traffic appropriately?
Thanks,
